# Is it possible to integrate the FaceId and TouchID in React-Native project?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement local authentication in my react-native mobile application. I'm using `react-native-touch-id`, But the **faceId module** is not working, it always asks for the fingerprint only. I did a lot of googling but was unable to find a satisfactory answer. It would be very helpful if anyone of you can help me with this.

```js
//this is for checking support of face id and touch id on your device
TouchID.isSupported(this.optionalConfigObject)
  .then((biometryType) => {
    if (biometryType === "FaceID") {
      console.log("FaceID is supported.");
    } else {
      console.log("TouchID is supported.");
      TouchID.authenticate("", this.optionalConfigObject)
        .then((success) => {
          Alert.alert("Authenticated Successfully");
          console.log("Success", success);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Cancel Pressed");
          BackHandler.exitApp();
        });
    }
  })
  // Failure code if the user's device does not have touchID or faceID enabled
  .catch((err) => {
    Alert.alert("", "Please add fingerprint from your device and try again", [
      {
        text: "OK",
        onPress: () => {
          console.log("OK Pressed"), BackHandler.exitApp();
        },
      },
    ]);
    console.log("error in catch=> " + err);
  });
```